# Continuity of the length operator from $C^0([a,b],X)$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, curves

Given $(X,d)$ metric space we define the length of a curve as follows :

$$l(\gamma, [a,b])=\sup\limits\limits_{P \in \mathbb{P}([a,b])}l(\gamma,P)$$

($\mathbb{P}[a,b]$ is the set of all possible partition of $[a,b]$)

Where for every partition $P \in \mathbb{P}([a,b])$,
$l(\gamma, P)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n d(\gamma(x_k),\gamma(x_{k+1}))$

I would prove that this last one is continuous as operator from $C^0([a,b],X)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Trying with the definition didn't see how to end : Let $\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2}$ be such that given $P = (x_{i})_{i=1,\cdots,n+1}$ with $d_{\infty}(\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2}) < \delta$ I'd like to state that $$|l(\gamma_{1},P)-l(\gamma_{2},P)| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |d(\gamma_{1}(x_{k}),\gamma_{1}(x_{k+1}))-d(\gamma_{2}(x_{k}),\gamma_{2}(x_{k+1}))| < \epsilon$$ but I got stuck since triangle's inequality didn't see to bring me somewhere.

Any help, solution or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It is continuous, even Lipschitz, as a sum and composition of Lip maps.

Comment: If you want to see continuity directly by triangle inequalities,  start from
$$d(\gamma_{1}(x_{k}),\gamma_{1}(x_{k+1}))\le d(\gamma_{1}(x_{k}),\gamma_{2}(x_{k}))+d(\gamma_{2}(x_{k}),\gamma_{2}(x_{k+1}))+d(\gamma_{2}(x_{k+1}),\gamma_{1}(x_{k+1}))\le  d(\gamma_{2}(x_{k}),\gamma_{2}(x_{k+1}))+2d_\infty(\gamma_{1} ,\gamma_{2}),$$
so by symmetry 
$$|d(\gamma_{1}(x_{k}),\gamma_{1}(x_{k+1}))-d(\gamma_{2}(x_{k}),\gamma_{2}(x_{k+1}))|\le 2d_\infty(\gamma_{1} ,\gamma_{2})$$
and summing over $k=1,\dots,|P|:=n$
$$|l(\gamma_1,P)-l(\gamma_2,P)|\le 2|P| d_\infty(\gamma_{1} ,\gamma_{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the map is continuous.  Consider $X=\mathbb R^2$ and compare two paths, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_{n}$ both going from the origin $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$.

Make $\gamma_1$ the straight line with length $\ell(\gamma_1) = 1$.  Take $\gamma_{n}$ to be a right-angled saw tooth with $n$ teeth, spaced $1/n$ apart and of side $\frac{1}{n\sqrt 2}$.  This can be formalised is you like, but by  construction, $$\ell(\gamma_n) = n\cdot \frac{\sqrt 2 }{n} = \sqrt 2.$$  But  $\lVert \gamma_1 - \gamma_n\rVert_\infty = 1/(2n)$ and for $n$ large enough this can be made as small as we like but the lengths of the two curves remain stubbornly apart.

Comment: But the OP asks for the continuity of the functional $\gamma\mapsto l(\gamma, P):=\sum\limits_{k} d(\gamma(x_k),\gamma(x_{k+1}))$, which  is of course continuous, a sum of $n$ continuous functionals. The length functional is just lower semicontinuous, as a superior envelope of a family of continuous functionals $ l(\gamma, P)$.

Comment: I think it was $\gamma \mapsto \sup \sum_k  d(\gamma(x_k), \gamma(x_{k+1}))$.  That I think is not continuous as my example shows, right?

Comment: As I understand, the OP asks for the continuity of the finite sum $l(\gamma, P)$. And yes, the supremum over all $P$  is only lower semicontinuous, and not continuous, as per your example.